How can I practice playing chords on the keyboard in order to accompany a song?
One of my dreams would be to be able to read chord notation and play the chords more or less intuitively to a song.
I think I have some of the theory, I know how to read the notation, and where to find all triads on the keyboard and their inversions. But I have nearly zero practice. I take a long time thinking about each note that belong to a chord. Usually I play the first chord, then I think about the notes of the second chord and I choose an inversion that minimizes movement. Then if there is a transition between two chords that I don't like I choose other inversions.
How could I start practicing playing chords to achieve something more natural and with less thinking? I don't know where to start.
Should I just keep doing this, or are there exercises equivalent to playing scales that I could try?

You have started. Practicing your improvised music may lead to being able to do it intuitively.

Thanks, I will keep working on it then!

The answer lies right there in the text of your question.
You know what you want to do, but you admit that you have zero practice at doing it.
I can tell you from my own experience that practice, and I mean a lot of it, makes perfect. When preparing for a gig or live performance, the only way we can  get any sleep the night before is to rehearse and practice the song (or songs) over and over again until confidence is achieved.
Is there by any chance an impediment or distraction in your house or flat that makes it hard for you to practice?
In my world, I find that I need a clear mind and no distractions at all before I can find the peace and internal harmony necessary to work on artistic endeavors. That means I get my chores done first and foremost, so that I don't have other attentions or deadlines hanging over my head. Then I announce, early and often, to my wife that I will be practicing in the music room.
I close the door. I isolate myself from the dogs and the street noise.
I relax. I put on the headphones if necessary, and then I practice the songs.
They say that a journey of a thousand miles starts with a single step.
Go ahead now.
Step out smartly, and put in the time.
Do the practice.

Thanks for your response. I think my biggest obstacle to practicing is not knowing if what I am doing is useful and going to make me progress, and not knowing if I am doing it right. I can still practice but my motivation does not last long enough. But if I am already doing it right.

Trip,
I'm a big believer in Performance Oriented Motivation.
When a musician has no gig or performance coming up, then the motivation to get better, and to achieve some level of proficiency, is absent.
When a musician has a gig coming up though, there is pressure to get it right, and to practice to comfortable proficiency. The motivation to practice, and to perfect the songs is high.
That has been my experience.
Even when I didn't have a band gig coming up, I would volunteer to go to a local old folks home, and play and sing great old songs for them!  Kept me sharp.

Another relevant saying is:  An amateur practises until they get it right; a professional practises until they can't get it wrong.  (Of course, reality's more complicated, but it's still something to think about.)  — If you're not being paid, then you need some other motivation for spending the time.  And the usual motivation is enjoyment — so find a way to make it fun!

I have been playing guitar for 60 years and still do not know what I'm doing. I improvise lead guitar parts for a country singer-songwriter.  It was not until 40 years into playing that I realized what scales were and that I play them.  I play notes of various scales to improvise lead guitar for a singer-songwriter.  I do not think of notes being played or anything I play in terms of music theory.  I listen to the melody of a song's vocals and then create a guitar melody from it.  Not sure if that is intuitive but I do it automatically.  I learned this about year seven.
